# Make tabs on the review/suggested-edits page linkable

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, hyperlinks, revisions-list

On [a review/suggested-edits page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/520076) there are 3 tabs:

- Inline
- Side-by-side
- Side-by-side Markdown

Please make them linkable, e.g. via URL hash. Depending on the edit, one view might fit better than the others so it would be useful if we can link directly to one of them.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a URL hash, it could just be a `?view=sidebysidemarkdown` or `inline` or `sidebyside`.

Comment: It seems that on different SE pages/edits the tab selected initially varies. Having linkable tabs helps here, too.